# Rigging Issue, that is effecting animation

Tags: animation

I notice whenever I make a model and rig it that whenever I try to rotate the head. Which is the very first bone I make, it rotates the whole model instead of just the head. I went through all the weight paint and made sure it was only the head painted but this did not fix it. Does anyone have an idea of what it is?

Comment: You could be parenting your bones backwards by mistake. The head should be the last child in the parenting order. This is why most tutorials you see online start making their bones pelvis-first, they generate parent-child automatically.

Comment: I do notice that the parent dotted line goes from the head to the center of nothing. Could this be indicating that

Comment: I also noticed that I rigged it in a way that all of the joints are connected on their ends. Whereas some of the rigs I am looking at they have the leg and arm joints not connected to the pelvis/head.

Answer (score 0):

Could use more info.  And if you can, can you share the .blend file?  Or just delete the armature and copy this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU

Comment: how would I share the blend file

Comment: Here ya go: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: I reversed the head bone, and it seems to have fixed my issue but I appreciate you trying to help

Comment: @Alexander if you solved your issue, could you post it as an answer and accept it? This way you close the question and reap the rep points, good both for you and the website. Check [ask] and [answer] for more details.